# Trying to get the series: [{ data: [], visible: false } function in HighChart working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am making a graph with multiple series parsed through json from a mysql database. I want, the graph to only display one serie from start.  HighChart there is an option doing exactly that, example below:

```
        series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        visible: false
    },
```

Since my series is defined: `series: []` I have not been able to work out how to adresse those series I want not visible. I am trying to learn by adapting tutorials to my own projects.
Here is my code

```
var options;

$(document).ready(function() {

    options = {
      chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Graf'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [],
            labels: {
            step: 6
        }

        },


          title: {
            text: 'Grafisk fremstilling af den valgte dag',
            y: 10,
            margin: 20
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },


        legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
    plotOptions: {
                series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
            },
            series: []
        }


   $.getJSON("dataNew.php", function(json) {
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            options.series[1] = json[2];
            options.series[2] = json[3];
            options.series[3] = json[4];
            options.series[4] = json[5];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });

});

  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $.getJSON("dataNew.php?dateParam="+dateText, function(json){
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            options.series[1] = json[2];
            options.series[2] = json[3];
            options.series[3] = json[4];
            options.series[4] = json[5];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
      }
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done it by hiding the series after the chart has been drawn.

So, you've got this code where you get your JSON:

```
$.getJSON("dataNew.php?dateParam="+dateText, function(json){
        options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
        options.series[0] = json[1];
        options.series[1] = json[2];
        options.series[2] = json[3];
        options.series[3] = json[4];
        options.series[4] = json[5];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
```

What I've done to make hide a specific series is to add the following after the chart draws:

```
chart.series[i].hide();
```

In your example, if you want to hide your second series, your code would look like:

```
$.getJSON("dataNew.php?dateParam="+dateText, function(json){
        options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
        options.series[0] = json[1];
        options.series[1] = json[2];
        options.series[2] = json[3];
        options.series[3] = json[4];
        options.series[4] = json[5];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        chart.series[1].hide();
    });
```

I think that should do it.